# UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:child_process" is not handled by plugins

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, next.js

I'm trying to use a dependency on https://github.com/appium/appium-adb in my nextjs app. While building the app i see the following error. What should be way to resolve this?

node:child_process
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:child_process" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.